# Getting an average from a nested calculation with averageifs in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, nested, average

i am trying to pull performance data togther from a csv. We have a design team with a list of tasks which arrive on their list, sit there until dealt with, and then get completed. For any given day i want to calculate:

1/ The number of tasks on the list (so i'm running countifs, with citeria being 1: the design team, 2: the task had arrived on the list by the given day, and 3: had not been completed by the given day. This works ok.

2/ I also want to know what the average amonth of days those tasks had been on the list on that given day. IN the data set i have the day they arrive, and the day they got completed, and i know the given day i want to calculate for. So i think i ned to nest a formula to calculate (given date - arrival date) into an averageifs formula with the same conditions as the task count.

I have set this up in a sheet using a helper column to give me the days elapsed, but in practice, i want to run this for a number of given days so cannot add a helper column for each query.

So i have =AVERAGEIFS($G:$G,B:B,"Design",$C:$C, "<"&I$1, $E:$E, ">="&I$1)
but where $G:$G is a calculation of the days elapsed =IF(C2<>"",SUM(I$1-C2),"")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbFKM.png)

Comment: So what is your question/problem?

Comment: I have tried just nesting the sum(I1-C2) in the criteria range of the averageifs formula but it doesnt work. I imagine i need an array formula...

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IF((B:B="Design")*($C:$C<I$1)*($E:$E=I$1),IFERROR(I1-C:C,"")))`  But it would be best if you would limit the references to just the range that has data.  Also depending on ones version, this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Thanks Scott -i tried that and got a #DIV/0! error. I tried it on a data set with no blanks in and the formula works. So i tried =AVERAGE(IF((C:C<>"")*(E:E<>"")*(B:B="Design")*($C:$C<M$1)*($E:$E>=M$1),IFERROR(M1-C:C,"1"))) to exclude the calculatuon from the rows with blank dates.  But still got the DIV error.

Comment: In fact, i want to include tasks which havearrived on the list, but not been completed